# Ubuntu Mate not booting, recovery not booting, initramfs & fsck no fix - after recent update

Tags: dual-boot, initramfs, fsck

after an update my Q957 mini PC won't boot into Linux, Windows (dualboot) is still working.

After trying to boot ubuntu, it immeadiately went into the **initramfs** shell mode.
The same happens, if i try to start the **recovery mode** or any other option at **advandced options**.

At the **initramfs** i tried the manual fcsk several times after normal booting and also during the recovery mode start up

`fsck /dev/sda6 -y`
followed by  `exit`  -  `reboot`  didn't work

After that, i tried to use a ubuntu usb drive and do it manually over the terminal

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda6`

With the same result of not fixing all bugs/issues

`Couldn't fix parent of Inode 11148355: Couldn't fInd parent directory entry`

All the output i have here in 2 pictures:
[image: part 1 - fsck output]

[image: part 2 - fsck output]